# $this->value losing, well, its value

Tags: php, variables

I have a problem with a PHP file I'm using, and I can't seem to find a solution.

In one part of the code the value for `$this->value` is set, and the value is set correctly according to my testing.

However, later in the same code `$this->value` is empty.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

class Padd_Input_Advertisement {

    protected $keyword;
    protected $value;
    protected $name;
    protected $description;

    function __construct($keyword,$name,$description='') {
        $this->keyword = $keyword;
        $this->value = unserialize(get_option($keyword));
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    public function get_keyword() {
        return $this->keyword;
    }

    public function set_keyword($keyword) {
        $this->keyword = $keyword;
    }

    public function get_value() {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function set_value($value) {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function get_name() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function set_name($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function get_description() {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function set_description($description) {
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    public function  __toString() {

        $strHTML  = '';
        $strHTML .= '<tr valign="top">';
        $strHTML .= '   <th scope="row"><label for="' . $this->keyword . '">' . $this->name . '</label></th>';
        $strHTML .= '   <td>';
        $strHTML .= '       <label for="' . $this->keyword. '_alt_desc">Short Description</label><br />';
        $strHTML .= '       <input name="' . $this->keyword . '_alt_desc" type="text" id="' . $this->keyword . '_alt_desc" value="' . $this->value->get_alt_desc() . '" size="80" /><br />';
        $strHTML .= '       <label for="' . $this->keyword. '_img_url">Image URL</label><br />';
        $strHTML .= '       <input name="' . $this->keyword . '_img_url" type="text" id="' . $this->keyword . '_img_url" value="' . $this->value->get_img_url() . '" size="80" /><br />';
        $strHTML .= '       <label for="' . $this->keyword. '_web_url">Website</label><br />';
        $strHTML .= '       <input name="' . $this->keyword . '_web_url" type="text" id="' . $this->keyword . '_web_url" value="' . $this->value->get_web_url() . '" size="80" />';
        $strHTML .= '       <br /><small>' . $this->description . '</small>';
        $strHTML .= '   </td>';
        $strHTML .= '</tr>';
        return $strHTML;
    }

}

?>
```

At the top in `function __construct`, the value is set, and I confirmed that this happens.

However, in the bottom function `function  __toString`, `$this->value` is blank.

Any idea what could be causing this?

**EDIT**

So, to recap, $this->value is set properly in the __construct function, but is blank in the __toString function.

**EDIT 2**

I should also mention that other variables that are set in the __construct function are working in the __toString function, like $this->keyword. It's jut $this->value that is going blank.

**Edit 3**
The class is called like this

```
$padd_options['advertisements'] = array(
    new Padd_Input_Advertisement(
        PADD_NAME_SPACE . '_ads_125125_1',
        'Square Ad 1 (125x125)',
        'The advertisement will be posted at the side bar.'
    ),
    new Padd_Input_Advertisement(
        PADD_NAME_SPACE . '_ads_125125_2',
        'Square Ad 2 (125x125)',
        'The advertisement will be posted at the side bar.'
    ),
    new Padd_Input_Advertisement(
        PADD_NAME_SPACE . '_ads_125125_3',
        'Square Ad 3 (125x125)',
        'The advertisement will be posted at the side bar.'
    ),
    new Padd_Input_Advertisement(
        PADD_NAME_SPACE . '_ads_125125_4',
        'Square Ad 4 (125x125)',
        'The advertisement will be posted at the side bar.'
    ),
);
```

Comment: `__toString()` is a magic method in php can you change that to some other name and try ?

Comment: Blank how? What does `var_dump` say inside `__toString`?

Comment: Well, I put some code in to output the values to a .txt file. At the top of the code the proper value was written to the file, at the bottom of the code only a blank file was written.

Comment: Where is `get_option()` defined? Getting a `Call to undefined function get_option()`

Comment: not familiar with "magic methods", but nowhere in the code is __toString() actually called like a regular function would be, so if I renamed this "magic" function to something else how would it get called?

Comment: get_option is defined, and working, in another file. In my original post I stated that the code with get_option in it actually sets the correct value, but when that variable is called later in the code it shows up blank.

Comment: have you tried changing the data type of $value from protected to private or public?

Comment: Didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I'm at a loss then, if you can confirm that it is setting `$value` in the `__construct` then somewhere between the time you set the val and retrieve the val it is being modified. The only thing I can recommend is walking through from the point of setting to the point of retrieving. You have probably already done this, but I don't know any other solutions to offer. Apologies...

Comment: WordPress uses a bunch of files, and so does the theme, and they are all "included" together. Trying to figure out how all of these files fit together, and where the problem is, seems like it would be a HUGE amount of work.

Comment: I just don't get how all of the variables are set properly, but only the "value" one ends up being empty just a few lines of code down.

Comment: if we can get a couple of upvotes, I'll be more than glad to start a bounty

Comment: Not available for bounty for another 2 days it says.

Comment: This must therefore mean that `set_value()` is called sometime after the constructor is called.  Just do a search ("Find in Files...") for `set_value(` in the other php files in your project.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be, and if I comment out the contents of that set_value function the same problem occurs, meaning the value is blank for some other reason.

Comment: This is precisely why I generally don't use things like WordPress for my own sites, since debugging someone else's code is a nightmare. However, this is a friend's site and someone else set it all up. A lot of time was spent getting it all ready, and looking the way they wanted, only to find out after there is a problem with the theme. Ugh...

Comment: How did you determine that the right value is set in the constructor? Do you have an example of said value? It seems that value isn't even an object from what I gathered, so perhaps a var_dump() of $this->value would be helpful too.

Comment: Your code does not show how you get to execute the __toString() method. Additionally you mention that the value is set correctly in the constructor, but fail to tell us which value it really is. What does the get_option() function do with the keyword?

Comment: Hi folks. Just to get confusion out. I suspect this is a Wordpress based project and get_option() is defined in core. FYI: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option

Comment: J. Wrong, you are right, it is a WordPress theme the problem is with.

Answer (score 11):

It's because unserialized object does *not* keep methods if they do not know the type of the class.

When you unserialize the result of the `get_keyword()` function call, if the class of the serialized object is not known, PHP will fallback on the special class `__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name`. This class is basically a dummy class : it doesn't have any method. However, it allows you to access to the attributes of the deserialized object.

So, if you want to be able to call the method of `$this->value` (which is what you are doing in `__toString`), you will have to include the file which declares the type of `$this->value` before calling unserialize.

**[edit]** You can check [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php) for more details about the unserialization process.

Comment: At the top of the script $this->value has a value. So if I want to take that value, and run it through the get_alt_desc function, how would I do that? The get_alt_desc function looks like this:     `public function get_alt_desc() {
  return $this->alt_desc;
 }`

Comment: And in that function $this->alt_desc has a value as far as I know.

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($this->value);` inside the `__toString` method ? If I'm right, you should see something like `object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ... }`. If it's the case, all you have to do is include the file which declares the actual type of the unserialized object.

Comment: I was outputting the values to a txt file when I was playing with it first. At the top $this->value wrote the proper value to the txt file, inside the toString function it didn't write anything because the value was blank. Would the var_dump show me something different?

Comment: And the other variables, like $this->keyword still have a value inside the toString function, and they are created the same way as $this->value

Comment: "Blank" can mean many things so ... do you mean NULL ? The `var_dump` function is kind of the standard way to inspect an object to know its type.

Comment: Nope, they are not created the same way as `$this->value`. The latter is created using the `unserialize` method, and that's a big difference.

Comment: What's probably happening is that the StdClass from unserialize is being returned by reference and scoped into the constructor. When the function expires, the object is destroyed and the reference blanked out. This is probably why the fix below works. Re-assigning the object to another variable forces the reference to remain intact.

Comment: @tazer84 That makes no sense at all, because assigning the value to a property keeps the value from being destroyed.

Comment: *Note* that `unserialize` returns an instance of `__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name` for classes not found at the time of unserialization (not `stdClass`, nor `StdClass`)

Answer (score 4):

This is what's causing you problems:

```
$this->value = unserialize(get_option($keyword));
```

As some others have previously pointed out, you could update your original post with the actual declarations of the `get_option()` function and the class that wraps the `get_alt_desc(), get_img_url(), get_web_url()` methods.

It can be assumed that the `get_option()` function returns a serialised object which implements the following **public** methods:

```
public function get_alt_desc() { /* custom code */ }
public function get_img_url() { /* custom code */ }
public function get_web_url() { /* custom code */ }
```

By serialising and unserialising your object you lose access to all of the above methods.
To avoid that, you need to modify the `get_option()` function to return the actual object instead of a serialized representation of it.

Assuming there is a `Value` class which represents your object:

```
class Value {
    protected $alt_desc;
    protected $img_url;
    protected $web_url;

    public function __construct($keyword) {
        $this->alt_desc = $keyword[0]; // some string build around $keyword
        $this->img_url = $keyword[1]; // some string build around $keyword 
        $this->web_url = $keyword[2]; // some string build around $keyword
    }

    public function get_alt_desc() {
        return $this->alt_desc;
    }

    public function get_img_url() {
        return $this->img_url;
    } 

    public function get_web_url() {
        return $this->web_url;
    }
}
```

Then you could modify your `get_option()` function to simply return an object:

```
function get_option($keyword) {
    /*
     * The code below is just an example
     * This function must return an object
     */
    return new Value($keyword);
}
```

Your `Padd_Input_Advertisement` constructor should be updated as following:

```
function __construct($keyword,$name,$description='') {
    $this->keyword = $keyword;
    // removed the unserialize call as it's not necessary anymore
    $this->value = get_option($keyword);
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->description = $description;
}
```

Comment: Correct analysis, we would really need more info from the OP to confirm the root cause of the problem.

Comment: It's wrong because `unserialize()` returns the actual object (see its documentation for more details). It's pointless to use an intermediate `Value` class.

Answer (score 1):

I would have added this as a comment, but I guess I dont have the reputation points to do that quite yet.

Have you tried to turn on error reporting?

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Comment: Yes, nothing of interest really. Warnings are generally not shown, and the fatal errors were already showing up on the page. I get "Fatal error: Call to a member function get_alt_desc() on a non-object", which I am suspecting is a result of the variable it's trying to use being blank.

Comment: See what happens when you create a function that does nothing but assign $value. Maybe make $value public for the time being and see if the object you save to $value exists and is accessible from outside of Padd_Input_Advertisement after you call that function. Are you calling __toString on the right instance of Padd_Input_Advertisement?

Comment: This is all a part of a theme for WordPress. I'm not really sure how to access any of these from outside of this file. Not sure what files are connected, etc. I'm not entirely sure about PHP classes and stuff, but I believe __toString is called for every instance of Padd_Input_Advertisement

Answer (score 1):

In Object oriented programming you have must have call function using `$this`.
In your function `__toString()` you have directly call function.

So you have called function of class like this

```
$this->set_name();
```

Comment: See "Edit 3" in my question.

Comment: what is this $this->value->get_alt_desc() ?

Comment: Another function in another file that gets called to return the a value. It should take $this->value and put it through the get_alt_desc function to return something different. But because the "value" in $this->value is blank it doesn't work.

Comment: can you include another file of function in your page?

Comment: Read this article may be help you http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.sleep

Comment: It's all part of a WordPress theme, so there are a lot of files that work together by being "included" and whatever.

Comment: Ok I have post link of Php magic method which you have used read it may be help you

Answer (score 1):

Using Magaling theme from [Padd Solutions](http://www.paddsolutions.com/wpmag/magalingreloaded/), that contains the script of the question, I added at index.php in the theme's directory the following code:

```
/*********************************TEST***********************************/
  $padd_options[ 'advertisements' ] = array( new Padd_Input_Advertisement( PADD_THEME_SLUG . '_ads_468060_1', 'Banner Ad 1 (468x60)', 'The advertisement is placed beside the site name in the header.' ),
                                             new Padd_Input_Advertisement( PADD_THEME_SLUG . '_ads_468060_2', 'Banner Ad 2 (468x60)', 'The advertisement is placed just below the title in Search Result page, Categories page, Tags page, Author page, and Archives page.' ),
                                             new Padd_Input_Advertisement( PADD_THEME_SLUG . '_ads_125125_1', 'Square Ad 1 (125x125)', 'The advertisement will be posted at the side bar.' ),
                                             new Padd_Input_Advertisement( PADD_THEME_SLUG . '_ads_125125_2', 'Square Ad 2 (125x125)', 'The advertisement will be posted at the side bar.' ),
                                             new Padd_Input_Advertisement( PADD_THEME_SLUG . '_ads_125125_3', 'Square Ad 3 (125x125)', 'The advertisement will be posted at the side bar.' ),
                                             new Padd_Input_Advertisement( PADD_THEME_SLUG . '_ads_125125_4', 'Square Ad 4 (125x125)', 'The advertisement will be posted at the side bar.' ), );

  echo var_dump( $padd_options[ 'advertisements' ] );

/*********************************TEST***********************************/
```

And got the following result, which shows the value is an array with several other values:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    object(Padd_Input_Advertisement)[286]
      protected 'keyword' => string 'magaling_ads_468060_1' (length=21)
      protected 'value' => 
        object(Padd_Advertisement)[282]
          private 'img_url' => string 'http://localhost/TestSite/wp-content/themes/magaling/images/advertisement-468x060.gif' (length=86)
          private 'alt_desc' => string 'Padd Solutions' (length=14)
          private 'web_url' => string 'http://www.paddsolutions.com' (length=28)
          private 'target' => string '_new' (length=4)
          private 'css_class' => string '' (length=0)
      protected 'name' => string 'Banner Ad 1 (468x60)' (length=20)
      protected 'description' => string 'The advertisement is placed beside the site name in the header.' (length=63)
  1 => 
    object(Padd_Input_Advertisement)[284]
      protected 'keyword' => string 'magaling_ads_468060_2' (length=21)
      protected 'value' => 
        object(Padd_Advertisement)[283]
          private 'img_url' => string 'http://localhost/TestSite/wp-content/themes/magaling/images/advertisement-468x060.gif' (length=86)
          private 'alt_desc' => string 'Padd Solutions' (length=14)
          private 'web_url' => string 'http://www.paddsolutions.com' (length=28)
          private 'target' => string '_new' (length=4)
          private 'css_class' => string '' (length=0)
      protected 'name' => string 'Banner Ad 2 (468x60)' (length=20)
      protected 'description' => string 'The advertisement is placed just below the title in Search Result page, Categories page, Tags page, Author page, and Archives page.' (length=131)
  2 => 
    object(Padd_Input_Advertisement)[279]
      protected 'keyword' => string 'magaling_ads_125125_1' (length=21)
      protected 'value' => 
        object(Padd_Advertisement)[278]
          private 'img_url' => string 'http://localhost/TestSite/wp-content/themes/magaling/images/advertisement-125x125.jpg' (length=86)
          private 'alt_desc' => string 'Padd Solutions' (length=14)
          private 'web_url' => string 'http://www.paddsolutions.com' (length=28)
          private 'target' => string '_new' (length=4)
          private 'css_class' => string '' (length=0)
      protected 'name' => string 'Square Ad 1 (125x125)' (length=21)
      protected 'description' => string 'The advertisement will be posted at the side bar.' (length=49)
  3 => 
    object(Padd_Input_Advertisement)[277]
      protected 'keyword' => string 'magaling_ads_125125_2' (length=21)
      protected 'value' => 
        object(Padd_Advertisement)[276]
          private 'img_url' => string 'http://localhost/TestSite/wp-content/themes/magaling/images/advertisement-125x125.jpg' (length=86)
          private 'alt_desc' => string 'Padd Solutions' (length=14)
          private 'web_url' => string 'http://www.paddsolutions.com' (length=28)
          private 'target' => string '_new' (length=4)
          private 'css_class' => string '' (length=0)
      protected 'name' => string 'Square Ad 2 (125x125)' (length=21)
      protected 'description' => string 'The advertisement will be posted at the side bar.' (length=49)
  4 => 
    object(Padd_Input_Advertisement)[275]
      protected 'keyword' => string 'magaling_ads_125125_3' (length=21)
      protected 'value' => 
        object(Padd_Advertisement)[273]
          private 'img_url' => string 'http://localhost/TestSite/wp-content/themes/magaling/images/advertisement-125x125.jpg' (length=86)
          private 'alt_desc' => string 'Padd Solutions' (length=14)
          private 'web_url' => string 'http://www.paddsolutions.com' (length=28)
          private 'target' => string '_new' (length=4)
          private 'css_class' => string '' (length=0)
      protected 'name' => string 'Square Ad 3 (125x125)' (length=21)
      protected 'description' => string 'The advertisement will be posted at the side bar.' (length=49)
  5 => 
    object(Padd_Input_Advertisement)[217]
      protected 'keyword' => string 'magaling_ads_125125_4' (length=21)
      protected 'value' => 
        object(Padd_Advertisement)[216]
          private 'img_url' => string 'http://localhost/TestSite/wp-content/themes/magaling/images/advertisement-125x125.jpg' (length=86)
          private 'alt_desc' => string 'Padd Solutions' (length=14)
          private 'web_url' => string 'http://www.paddsolutions.com' (length=28)
          private 'target' => string '_new' (length=4)
          private 'css_class' => string '' (length=0)
      protected 'name' => string 'Square Ad 4 (125x125)' (length=21)
      protected 'description' => string 'The advertisement will be posted at the side bar.' (length=49)
```

I don't know why the value in your script is lost, but there is something missing or wrong in the theme you are using or in the way you are calling the function.The supplied information is not enough, by the way.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
Is unserialise call needed at all in:

```
$this->value = unserialize(get_option($keyword));
```

get_option returns unserialized object already (as long as it it was saved by update_option() - which automatically serialises object if necessary before saving it in database)

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I suspect the problem is with the way you serialize the object.

You need make sure the during serialization process *(conversion to string representation)* the type of the serialized object is KNOWN. Only then you can successfully unserialize *(convert back from string representation to object)* it back.

To answer your another question regarding `_toString()`. This function is called magically by PHP when you are trying to use your object in a string context (when you try to echo the object for example). You DO NOT call this function directly.

Here is the single php file which demonstrates WORKING flow; with comments to the parts where you should look for traps *(causes of problems)*. Save it as index.php and run to see the results.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

class Padd_Input_Advertisement {
    protected $keyword;
    protected $value;
    protected $name;
    protected $description;

    function __construct($keyword,$name,$description='') {
        $this->keyword = $keyword;
        $this->value = unserialize(get_option($keyword));
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->description = $description;        
    }

    public function get_keyword()         { return $this->keyword; }
    public function set_keyword($keyword) { $this->keyword = $keyword; }
    public function get_value()           {  return $this->value; }
    public function set_value($value)     { $this->value = $value; }
    public function get_name()            { return $this->name; }
    public function set_name($name)       { $this->name = $name; }
    public function get_description()     { return $this->description;}
    public function set_description($description) { $this->description = $description; }
    public function  __toString() {

        $strHTML  = '';
        $strHTML .= '<tr valign="top">';
        $strHTML .= '   <th scope="row"><label for="' . $this->keyword . '">' . $this->name . '</label></th>';
        $strHTML .= '   <td>';
        $strHTML .= '       <label for="' . $this->keyword. '_alt_desc">Short Description</label><br />';
        $strHTML .= '       <input name="' . $this->keyword . '_alt_desc" type="text" id="' . $this->keyword . '_alt_desc" value="' . $this->value->get_alt_desc() . '" size="80" /><br />';
        $strHTML .= '       <label for="' . $this->keyword. '_img_url">Image URL</label><br />';
        $strHTML .= '       <input name="' . $this->keyword . '_img_url" type="text" id="' . $this->keyword . '_img_url" value="' . $this->value->get_img_url() . '" size="80" /><br />';
        $strHTML .= '       <label for="' . $this->keyword. '_web_url">Website</label><br />';
        $strHTML .= '       <input name="' . $this->keyword . '_web_url" type="text" id="' . $this->keyword . '_web_url" value="' . $this->value->get_web_url() . '" size="80" />';
        $strHTML .= '       <br /><small>' . $this->description . '</small>';
        $strHTML .= '   </td>';
        $strHTML .= '</tr>';
        return $strHTML;
    }

}

//Just a sample of the class representing your option object
class Class_Of_Value {
    protected $alt_desc;
    protected $img_url;
    protected $web_url;

    public function __construct($keyword) {
        $this->alt_desc = 'description'; 
        $this->img_url = 'image'; 
        $this->web_url = 'web'; 
    }

    public function get_alt_desc() { return $this->alt_desc; }
    public function get_img_url()  { return $this->img_url; } 
    public function get_web_url()  { return $this->web_url; }
}

//Sample of a CORRECT get_option function.
function get_option($keyword) {
    //THIS IS IMPORTANT
    $valueObject = new Class_Of_Value($keyword);
    //MAKE SURE THAT TYPE of serialised value is KNOWN
    return serialize($valueObject); 
}
//Here is the root cause of your problem.
//Wordpress' get_option() DOES NOT serialise returned objects. It returns just value of an option pulled from database!
//Hence you can't call methods  $this->value->get_alt_desc() etc.


define ('PADD_NAME_SPACE', ''); //dummy definition of the constant for the sake of PHP Notices

$padd_options['advertisements'] = array(
    new Padd_Input_Advertisement(
        PADD_NAME_SPACE . '_ads_125125_1',
        'Square Ad 1 (125x125)',
        'The advertisement will be posted at the side bar.'
    ),
    new Padd_Input_Advertisement(
        PADD_NAME_SPACE . '_ads_125125_2',
        'Square Ad 2 (125x125)',
        'The advertisement will be posted at the side bar.'
    ),
    new Padd_Input_Advertisement(
        PADD_NAME_SPACE . '_ads_125125_3',
        'Square Ad 3 (125x125)',
        'The advertisement will be posted at the side bar.'
    ),
    new Padd_Input_Advertisement(
        PADD_NAME_SPACE . '_ads_125125_4',
        'Square Ad 4 (125x125)',
        'The advertisement will be posted at the side bar.'
    ),
);

//Here __toString will be called by PHP outputing your HTML form filled with object values.
echo($padd_options['advertisements'][0]);
```

Suggested solution to your problem is to make sure that the Wordpress option is properly serialised (with object type) prior to being saved in database (WP’s `update_option()`). 
So, then get_option will return serialized string which will then be properly unserialised in your `__construct` method.

Comment: The object type *name* is always serialized, iirc. However, the type *declaration* must be available before unserializing. (Which is the opposite of what you stated : of course that the type of the object is known when serializing. It wouldn't have been instanciate if it wasn't the case :)

Comment: Yes you are right. But object type is serialised only if object itself is serialised as well. Problem I've outlined is the fact the the object might be not serialised at all. I checked Wordpress Codex and it led me to another answer.

Answer (score 1):

did you try to force the operator -> precedence?

I mean, from this:

```
$this->value->get_alt_desc()
```

to this:

```
($this->value)->get_alt_desc()
```

maybe your PHP interpreter is trying to evaluate `value->get_alt_desc()`

Answer (score -2):

So, I've figured out a solution to this problem that makes the code work as expected. It doesn't resolve the root cause, but it's more of a workaround.

In the __construct function I added:

```
$this->value2 = $this->value;
```

And then in the code that was causing the error I changed:

```
$this->value->get_alt_desc()
```

to

```
$this->value2->get_alt_desc()
```

So all of the code was working, except for that one variable $this->value was losing its value, and once I used a different variable name everything worked as it should have.

Comment: -1, because you decided to add even more confusion to the problem.

Comment: @SherwinFlight you should not be accepting your answer. Your question is "`Any idea what could be causing this?`". Your answer does not answer that and the  top voted answer from Nison does.

Comment: It seems that "value" have a special meaning in PHP.

Comment: This is what fixed the problem. I guess the issue is how I worded my question. Instead of asking "Any idea what could be causing this?" I should have asked "What is the easiest way to fix this?".