# $this->constant or $this->var in class constructor

Tags: php, laravel, class, constructor, constants

I want to know if the code below is wrong in terms of structure and if it is not can any one explain to me why it actually works

```
class ClassA extends ClassB
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->FILE_DIRECTORY = 'book/auido';
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $file_directory = $this->FILE_DIRECTORY;
        return $file_directory
    }
}
```

The above returns

```
'book/auido'
```

i understand that the right way of doing this would be to `public static $variable = 'string';` and the use `self::$variable;` to access it in any methods in the class.

but i have a feeling that the approach i have used above is wrong as i don't fully understand what is happing and why it works.

Comment: all depends how you intend to use this class and what it does. maybe a static variable makes sense, maybe it does not. maybe hard coding a value makes sense, maybe it does not :)

Comment: @lagbox would this qualify as a constant? regardless of being passed in a constructor.

Comment: found the answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408037/php-this-var-what-does-that-mean) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244321/this-value-losing-well-its-value)

Answer (score 0):

How you’ve used `FILE_DIRECTORY` here is not a constant, it’s just a variable written in uppercase.

This is how you would use it as a constant, for reference:

```php
class ClassA extends ClassB
{
    const FILE_DIRECTORY = 'book/auido';

    public function index()
    {
        $file_directory = self::FILE_DIRECTORY;
        return $file_directory
    }
}
```

Normally people use constants to mean something that can never change, such as ISO country code. Anything within your domain is subject to change, so a config would normally be better at that point.